# What to do with components that re-render frequently?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What to do with components that re-render frequently?

What I'm trying to do is to have a value entered in a TextInput and have that value exposed in multiple squares (Views).

For example, if I type 12345, it will appear in the view as [1][2][3][4][5].
However, we'll draw 5 views initially, and if the input is longer than 5 characters, we'll draw 5 new views and keep repeating.

```js
   data = "12345".split(""); 
data.map(item => <View>{item}</View>
```

and touch a view to move the cursor to that location to continue typing. For example, if you touch [3] and then type a, it will look like [1][2][3][a][4][5].
As a result, the app is slowing down as all those views are re-rendered, resulting in the error below.

> Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code

It's hard to use memo because it keeps re-rendering (because it changes the values inside the view).
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Use `key`s for the elements in the array, and use `memo`

Comment: You can use onBlur instead of onChange. onBlur will trigger a rerender once you focus outside the input. Also, as @Bergi said, you need to use unique keys for the <View> element so React knows to leave existing views alone. memo might help, but only if the View is an expensive component. Otherwise it will just slow the performance even more.